# Do save games travel between the online and downloadable versions of Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've just started playing the download version of Minecraft in single player mode.  I was wondering how the download and online versions interact in terms of save games.

Does the online version store and load saves to and from the computer that you're playing on or are they stored online for playing anywhere?  Are my saves from the download version stored online a la Steam Cloud or are they only on my computer?  Can I load my download version saves with the online version anywhere, on the machine I was playing on or not at all?  Etc...

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They are stored on your local computer.  If you play the online mode from separate computers, you will either need separate saves or you will need to manually move the saves over.

The downloadable version and the online version use the same saves, however, so you can switch back and forth between those and you will be able to continue to play the same game.